# Can a p-normed matrix space be embadded to a higher p-normed space

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

For any $1\leq p\leq\infty$, the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ with norm $\displaystyle||x||=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^\frac1p$.

Defined its linear transformation space $M^n_p$ associated norm $\displaystyle||A||=\sup\limits_{||x||=1}||Ax||$.

So for any $p$ and $n>1$, can we find $n^2\leq N<\infty$ so that $M^n_p$ can be isometric to a sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^N_p$? If yes, how to calculate the minimum of each $N$ when given $n$ and $p$.

Comment: For $1<p<\infty$, the answer is negative. Indeed, the norm of $\mathbb{R}^N_p$ is strictly convex, while  the operator norm is not: e.g., the matrices
$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0 & t\end{pmatrix}$, $-1\le t\le 1$ 
all have the operatorm norm of $1$ for every $p$.

Comment: Oh it's sup, and thanks you:-)